# Spring Thymeleaf th:selected on EnumList with multiple selection

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have this enum

```
enum Types{
  A, B
}
```

I have a form class

```
public class MyForm {
   private Types[] types;
   //getter setters
}
```

here is my form with select

```
<form th:action="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}" th:object="${myForm}" method="POST" id="form">

<select name="types" multiple="" id="testSelect"
  th:each="type : ${T(com.test.Types).values()}"
  th:value="${type}" 
  th:text="${type}"
  th:selected="*{types != null AND #arrays.contains(types, type)}"
  >
</select>

</form>
```

here is the error i am getting.

```
 Property or field 'type' cannot be found on object of type 'com.test.MyForm' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you have a typo, it should be `type !=` and not types `!=`. Also, you are using `*` in your selected, instead of `$`. Also, I believe you are using `#list.contains()` of Thymeleaf in a way that shouldn't work. You should use the whole function, just like this `#list.contains(types, type)`. One last thing, the `selected`, `value` and `text` tags should should go in the `option` element, not the `select`. In the end your code should look like the following one.

```
<select name="types" multiple="" id="testSelect">
    <option th:each="type : ${T(com.test.Types).values()}"
         th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}"
         th:selected="${types != null AND #arrays.contains(types, type)}">
    </option>
</select>
```

One last thing, I am not sure where did the variable `types` came from, I am assuming you initialized it somewhere.

Comment: types is coming from form th:object="${myForm}" please look at the MyForm class.

Comment: What error did you get? Some types is actually a field from your form? Is this a newly created object? Or are you sending an already existing object?

Comment: i am submiting my form

Comment: I have updated my question now i am using Type array instead of list and also print the error what i got please have a look

Comment: Ok, I changed the code and it should work now.  I just tested it out in one of my applications with a similar structure. The problem was that I didn't know what types was. Also, remember adding the selected in your option, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Alright it solved half of my problem. form submitted successfully, after after post when page load with data the selected options are reset to empty selection.

Comment: and why are u iterating on select tag instead of option tag

Comment: So after the post, the selected option is not selected anymore? Is that what's happening? For your second question, that is just an error. I forgot to pass it down to the option. I just edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: yes, i print the posted data on console, all selected options are posting correctly but selected option is not selected anymore

Comment: So after your post, you go back to the same page? Could I see your Controller method?

Comment: i am posting to the same controller and same controller is rendring view no redirections between. because all other fields are populating except this one.

Comment: Do you mind sharing both their code? You sure you are setting the same attributes? There shouldn't be no difference between.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to change your form backing bean to have some collection of your enumerations, instead of array such as:

```
public class MyForm {
  private List<Types> types = new ArrayList<Types>();
  //getter setters
}
```

Then before you render the form, you can just fill this array with types, which you want to be preselected in the controller just by adding them to the list.

Then should be able to simply skip th:selected logic...

```
<select th:field="*{types}" multiple="multiple" id="testSelect">
    <option th:each="type : ${T(com.test.Types).values()}"
       th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Thymeleaf will do the magic for you ;-)

Comment: i would like to use th:selected not thymeleaf auto setting.